# C# How to write one byte at an offset?

Tags: c#, io, byte

Im trying to write a single byte at a certain location in a file. This is what im using at the moment:

```
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open));
bw.BaseStream.Seek(0x6354C, SeekOrigin.Begin);
bw.Write(0xB0);
bw.Close();
```

The problem is that BinaryWriter.Write(args) writes a four-byte signed integer at the position. I wish to only write one byte at the particular location. And then later possibly two bytes else where, how I specify how many bytes to write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to use a high-level BinaryWriter just to write a simple byte to a stream - It's more efficient and tidy just to do this:

```
Stream outStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
outStream.Seek(0x6354C, SeekOrigin.Begin);
outStream.WriteByte(0xb0);
```

(In general you also shouldn't really Seek after attaching a BinaryWriter to your stream - the BinaryWriter should be in control of the stream, and changing things "behind its back" is a bit dirty)

Comment: Manually seeking the stream shouldn't cause any problems. And it is necessary when writing a record which includes the record size at the start, and when you do not yet know what the actual size of the record will be, which isnt that uncommon.

Answer (score 3):

change

```
bw.Write(0xB0);
```

to

```
bw.Write((byte)0xB0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could cast to byte:

```
bw.Write((byte)0xB0);
```

This should cause the correct overloaded version of Write to be invoked.